# Make a phone call from a server--what services are out there?

Tags: phone-call, ivr

I am looking to make a phone call from software and have the software read a message to the recipient. I have been using Asterisk, but have found it somewhat are to maintain and it was a pain to configure. I'm wondering if there are any services where you can send it a piece of text and a phone number and it will read it to the recipient of the phone call.

I am in Canada and making calls within Canada. The service does not need to accept calls. I am working with an AMP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Twilio](http://www.twilio.com) is your best bet, I think. Look into the documentation on Dial and Play. Also, if this is a one-off and you don't want to do lots of programming, check out the Twimlets in Twilio Labs, specifically [Call Me](http://labs.twilio.com/twimlets/callme).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Katalina 'VoiceGuide' a windows-based CTI system. It can handle Text-To-Speech applications. see: [www.voiceguide.com](http://www.voiceguide.com)

Also, MS have a server-based telephony system.

There are others, but I would consider the 2 above as prime candidates.