# Make a phone call in android even the app is closed

Tags: android, firebase

i'm currently developing an app that read data from firebase and when the data change it must phone call a specific person to notifiy them and this must happen even if the app is closed i tried with Intent but it just work when app is opened is there a way to make this possible even if the app is closed?

Comment: I doubt it, if there is you will need explicit permissions. Usually it's best to have an external backend service that would handle this. This is why most companies will charge for services like this. Making calls on the phone network always costs money.

Comment: @sakurashinken yeah this app should call someone but he will be aware that this app called him and he won't answer it's just like to notify him that some data changed ,so is there any possible way to make this happen.

Comment: Twillio is the goto service. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459189/make-a-phone-call-from-a-server-what-services-are-out-there

Comment: @sakurashinken will twillio allows me to make phone calls when app is closed?

Comment: You would make a backend service on a remote server that would watch the data you want to monitor. When it changes, it would look up your user's phone number (which you can store when they install the app) and use the twillio API to make a call. You wound't handle the call or data monitoring in the app itself, but in your backend server that the app would load data from.